# Prove if $a>0, b>0$, $P(X\cdot Y\le b)\ge P(X\le b/a)-P(Y>a)$, where $X,Y$ random variables?

Tags: probability

I don't know why I am having such trouble with this. I've tried using De Morgan but haven't made much progress yet.

Comment: Try drawing the regions in the x-y plane corresponding to each event.

Comment: Nevermind, did it via De Morgan. You are welcome to post another technique though.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually false without additional assumptions on the supports of $X$ and $Y$.

Try $a=b=1$, with $X=Y=-2$ (deterministic) for a counter-example,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(XY\leq a) &= 0\\
\mathbb P(X\leq b/a) &= 1\\
\mathbb P(Y> a) &= 0
\end{align*}

However, you may **either** suppose additionally that:

- $X>0$ almost surely;
- $Y>0$ almost surely;
- or simply replace the formula with $$P(X\cdot Y\le b)\ge P(\lvert X\rvert\le b/a)-P(\lvert Y\rvert>a)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
P(XY ≤ b) & \ge & P (X ≤ b/a, Y \le a) \quad \quad \leftarrow \mbox{caution, see correction below}\\
P( Y > a) & \ge & P (X ≤ b/a, Y  >  a)\\
P(XY ≤ b)+P( Y > a) & \ge & P (X ≤ b/a, Y \le a) + P (X ≤ b/a, Y  >  a)=P (X ≤ b/a)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: $P(XY \le b)  \ge  P (X \le b/a, Y \le a)$ is true when everything is non-negative but FelixCQ's counter example applies here too.